# How to distribute parent element's width among child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using twitter bootstrap for a site and basically I have a order list within a div element. When the screen get resized to 768px, I want parent's div width, equally distributed among all child list.

Do I need use media queries and JavaScript? Can anyone help me getting started with this concept please? The code may look like followings--

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-7 col-lg-9 pull-right process-tab">
            <ol class="investment-pagination c-white pull-right process-tab-bar">
                <li data-tab-target="goalName" class="active">1</li>
                <li data-tab-target="amountTerm">2</li>
                <li data-tab-target="riskLevel">3</li>
                <li data-tab-target="investment">4</li>
                <li data-tab-target="accountType">5</li>
                <li data-tab-target="fund">6</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**EDIT:**  [bootply.com/ibnLAYxmbB](http://%20bootply.com/ibnLAYxmbB)

Comment: Could you make a demo of what you ahve so far and show us what you have tried?

Comment: The site isn't on a live-server. Is there anyway I can add screen shoots?

Comment: Screeen shots won't be much use...try [**Bootply.com**](http://www.bootply.com/new)

Comment: Here is the links mate - http://www.bootply.com/ibnLAYxmbB

Comment: So when the screen size gets resized, I would very much like each li to get equal width from its parents div (in this case, col-xs-12, which I think 768px)

Comment: @Abhitalks Thaks mate. Its solved my problem. Really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your parent is not `col-xs-12` it is `col-xs-6`. So, first fix that.
2. Add a media query for `max-width: 768px`
3. Make your `ol` as `display: table`
4. Make your `li` as `display:table-cell` and remove `float` and `width`

In effect, your CSS would look like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .investment-pagination { display: table; width: 100%; }
  .investment-pagination li { display: table-cell; width: auto; float: none; }

}
```

**Demo: http://bootply.com/CRMNgpsjMV**